# Echo Sites With Same IP In Majority

Tags: php, sql

I want to know how can I Echo 'M' with some sites only when the sites IP is in mass majority in the Database like if 
12.43.121.2 IP is 9 times in 9 different sites then only it should echo 'V' with those sites having majority same IP if 14.821.83.21 IP is only 3 times with 3 different sites then it should not echo'M' here is what i have tried but it's all in vain

```
 <?
 $shm= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE url='$od[url]'");
 while ($getm = mysql_fetch_array($shm)){
     if($getm['ips']=="$od[ips]"){
         echo "V";
     }
     else{
         echo"";
     }
 }
 ?>
```

Another Try

```
 <?
 $shm= mysql_query("SELECT COUNT FROM dom WHERE ips='$od[ips]'");

 if($shm<3) ///Confused here what to do?// {
 echo "V";
 }
 else{
 echo"";
 }

 ?>
```

My Final Code(Wordking) :)

```
<?
$shm= mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM domain WHERE ips='$od[ips]'");
if($od['ips']=="")
{
}
else{
while ($getm= mysql_fetch_array($shm)){
$mass = $getm[0];
if($mass>"10"){
echo "V";
}
else{
echo"";
}
}
} 
?>
```

Comment: `here is what i have tried` I'm not seeing what you have tried. Did you forget to post it, maybe?

Comment: i had , put somehow wasnt visible, now it is visible

Comment: Shouldn't you `COUNT()` the rows that contain a certain IP? Like `SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM table WHERE ip_field='192.168.1.2'`. Also, what do fields 'url' and 'ips' contain?

Comment: @nadirs URL contains sites url and ips contains ips
yeah you are right that i should get count but then how to echo "M" with majority?

Comment: should it be like this
       <?
      $shm= mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM kayitlar WHERE ips='$onhold[ips]'");
 
      if($shm<3) ///confused here what to do here/// {
      echo "M";
      }
      else{
      echo"";
      }
  
      ?>

Comment: Use an alias for `COUNT` so you can refer to it later when you fetch data. `mysql_fetch_array` is still needed. Also, I'm still not sure what the task is: do you want to check all the IPs and count how many times each IP is repeated?

Comment: @nadris yeah how many times that IP has come up with different URL(sites)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This counts how many different urls are there in the database for each IP. The IP that is the most repeated IP, it's echoed along with character 'M'. You can adjust it to your needs.

```
<?php
 $shm = mysql_query("SELECT ips, COUNT(ips) AS how_many FROM (
     SELECT DISTINCT url, ips FROM kayitlar) AS temp GROUP BY ips ORDER BY how_many DESC;'");
 if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($shm)) {
     if ($row['how_many'] > 9) {
         echo $row['ips'] . ': M';
     }
     else {
         echo '';
     }
 }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($getm['ips']=="$onhold[ips]") {
```

should be (for a start):

```
if($getm['ips']==$onhold["ips"]) {
```

also, i dont understand that $onhold["ips"] (i do the "url")

Answer (score 0):

what i would do with "complex variables" and double quoted strings is place them beteen curly braces{} and use normal formatting.

your code would look like this then

$shm= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kayitlar WHERE url='{$onhold[’url’]}'"); while ($getm = mysql_fetch_array($shm)){

if($getm['ips']=="{$onhold[’ips’]}"){ echo "M"; } else{ echo""; } } ?>